# S4 constructors and prototypes

Tags: r, constructor, r-s4

Looking through Hadley Wickham's S4 wiki:
https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S4

```
setClass("Person", representation(name = "character", age = "numeric"), 
  prototype(name = NA_character_, age = NA_real_))
hadley <- new("Person", name = "Hadley")
```

How can we design a constructor for Person (like this)

```
Person<-function(name=NA,age=NA){
 new("Person",name=name,age=age)
}
```

that doesn't do this:

```
> Person()
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class "Person" object: 1: invalid object for slot "name" in class "Person": got class "logical", should be or extend class "character"
invalid class "Person" object: 2: invalid object for slot "age" in class "Person": got class "logical", should be or extend class "numeric"
```

Comment: An update: setClass returns a default constructor:

Person <- SetClass( "Person", ... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the answer is right there in your example:

```
Person<-function(name=NA_character_,age=NA_real_){
 new("Person",name=name,age=age)
}
```

yields

```
> Person()
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] NA

Slot "age":
[1] NA

> Person("Moi")
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Moi"

Slot "age":
[1] NA

> Person("Moi", 42)
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Moi"

Slot "age":
[1] 42
```

However, that is fairly un-S4 and duplicates the default values already assigned in the class definition. Maybe you'd prefer to do

```
Person <- function(...) new("Person",...)
```

and sacrifice the ability to call without named arguments?

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer giving the end-user some hints about argument types than the suggestion to use `...` by @themel. Also forgoing the prototype and using `length(x@name) == 0` as an indication that the field is un-initialized, using a `People` class rather than `Person`, reflecting the vectorized structure of R, and using `...` in the constructor so derived classes can also use the constructor.

```
setClass("People",
    representation=representation(
        firstNames="character",
        ages="numeric"),
    validity=function(object) {
        if (length(object@firstNames) != length(object@ages))
            "'firstNames' and 'ages' must have same length"
        else TRUE
    })

People = function(firstNames=character(), ages=numeric(), ...)
    new("People", firstNames=firstNames, ages=ages, ...)
```

And

```
People(c("Me", "Myself", "I"), ages=c(NA_real_, 42, 12))
```